# SQL Server endpoint port

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cluster-computing

I have two virtual machines with SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on them. They both can see each other, but I can't create mirrored cluster, as the have same endpoint port number.

Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
USE master; GO CREATE ENDPOINT [CustomConnection] STATE = STARTED AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 1500, LISTENER_IP =ALL) FOR TSQL() ; GO
```